# blank rootviewcontroller page is added by default from iOS 4.3 and above

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5

I have an application in which I use a navigation controller to present hierarchical data using customViewControllers. However in our application specification, we need to have a 'home button' in every page which should take the user back to the rootviewcontroller page. To achieve this I have a launchHomePage method defined in all the custom view controllers which goes like this:

```
- (void) launchHomePage {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

This was working perfectly on iOS 4.2. However in iOS4.3 and iOS5 when the 'home button' is clicked it is displaying a blank tableview. To debug the issue I tried to see the list of viewControllers in the navigationController before calling popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

```
- (void) launchHomePage {

    if(self.navigationController) {

        [self printViewControllers:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];

        [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't retrieve navigationcontroller\n");
    }
}

- (void) printViewControllers:(NSArray *) viewControllers {

    if(viewControllers) {
        NSLog(@"Number of viewcontrollers in navigationController's array is %d\n", 
              [viewControllers count]);

        int i = 1;
        for(UIViewController *viewController in viewControllers) {
            NSLog(@"viewController %d is %@ and has title %@\n", i++, viewController, [viewController title]);
        }
    }
}
```

For the same execution sequence, following is the output of the above method in iOS5.0 vs. iOS4.2  :

```
iOS5:

Number of viewcontrollers in navigationController's array is 3
viewController 1 is <RootViewController: 0x86259c0> and has title (null)
viewController 2 is <RootViewController: 0x9115680> and has title MainPage
viewController 3 is <FirstPageViewController: 0x9141bd0> and has title FirstPage


iOS4.2:
Number of viewcontrollers in navigationController's array is 2
viewController 1 is <RootViewController: 0x624d520> and has title MainPage
viewController 2 is <FirstPageViewController: 0x651ce10> and has title FirstPage
```

I am not able to figure out how/why there is a blank page (with title null) as the root of the navigationController. Appreciate any help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I think its related to using the xib file to load the UINavigationController but I haven't been able to confirm.  Either way, I originally had this (navcontroller is the UINavigationController that is loaded from the xib file, so I didn't alloc it, since I thought the xib file did that):

```
[navController initWithRootViewController:rootController];
```

I replaced it with this

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
```

and the popToRootViewController method now works as it originally did, pre-iOS 4.3 and iOS 5.  I also tested it on iOS 3.1.3 and it works as intended.